# What do these ATA error messages mean?

Tags: disk, log

```
[  108.138078] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x40000 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen

[  108.138085] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[  108.138090] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }

[  108.138095] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  108.138106] ata1.00: cmd 61/c8:90:00:10:c6/03:00:5f:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 495616 out

                        res 40/00:94:00:10:c6/00:00:5f:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)

[  108.138111] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

[  108.138116] ata1: hard resetting link

[  108.453212] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)

[  108.465868] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133

[  108.465881] ata1: EH complete

[  118.396927] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x8000 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen

[  118.396936] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error

[  118.396942] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }

[  118.396949] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

[  118.396964] ata1.00: cmd 61/50:78:d8:44:a8/03:00:70:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 434176 out

                        res 40/00:7c:d8:44:a8/00:00:70:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)

[  118.396970] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

[  118.396978] ata1: hard resetting link

[  118.712315] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)

[  118.725463] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133

[  118.725485] ata1: EH complete

[  133.731533] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x7c00 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen

[  133.731537] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error

[  133.731540] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }

[  133.731543] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

[  133.731549] ata1.00: cmd 61/f0:50:c8:17:91/00:00:70:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 122880 out

                        res 40/00:74:70:a4:85/00:00:70:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)

[  133.731552] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[  133.731554] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  133.731559] ata1.00: cmd 61/a8:58:d8:64:91/02:00:70:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 348160 out
                        res 40/00:74:70:a4:85/00:00:70:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)

[  133.731562] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

[  133.731564] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

[  133.731569] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:60:78:13:84/00:00:70:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 4096 out

                        res 40/00:74:70:a4:85/00:00:70:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)

[  133.731572] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

[  133.731574] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

[  133.731579] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:68:b8:13:84/00:00:70:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 4096 out

                        res 40/00:74:70:a4:85/00:00:70:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)

[  133.731581] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

[  133.731583] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

[  133.731588] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:70:70:a4:85/00:00:70:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 8192 out

                        res 40/00:74:70:a4:85/00:00:70:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)

[  133.731591] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

[  133.731594] ata1: hard resetting link

[  134.047939] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)

[  134.061108] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133

[  134.061136] ata1: EH complete
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this drive failure or something else?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141862/is-this-drive-failure-or-something-else)

Answer (score 3):

You have NCQ disk errors, [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing)

Edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and change the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

Save the changes and update GRUB, and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub

reboot
```

And see if the problem is solved. If not, undo these changes, and suspect a bad SATA port, SATA cable, or a possible bad hard drive.