# How to solve the "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." Error?

Tags: 12.04

As soon as I boot in I get the error as mentioned on the title.

I have the following software, let me know if you need more info to troubleshoot:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 6.2.0-33-generic

I was following this solution, [After Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04: "Oh no! Something went wrong"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong)

So I logged in to a virtual terminal and typed
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

As soon as it starts to install/upgrade the packages I get the following error

```
After this operation, 883 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Extracting templates from packages: 100%

Preconfiguring packages

[1213.587190] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80000000 SErr 0x40000 action 0x0

[1213.589701] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008

[1213.592140] atai: SError: Commake

[ 1213.594557] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED [1213.597034] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:18:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 4096 in

[1213.597034]

res 41/40:00:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (madia error) <F>

[1213.601848] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR} [ 1219.604282] ata1.00: error: UNC 1

[1213,640795] I/O error, dev sda, sector 3692523528 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg i prio class 2

[1216.327151] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80 SErr 0x40000 action 0x0

[ 1216.329625] ata1.00: irq stat 0x40000008 (1216.332057] atai: SError: [ CommHake ]

[1216.334476] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED [1216.336844] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:38:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dme 4096 in

[1216.336844]

res 41/40:00:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>

[1216.341598 ] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR! }

1216.344000] ata1.00: error: UNC

1216.380814] I/O error, dev sda, sector 3692523528 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2

1219.067104] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x40100 SErr 0x40000 action 0x0

1219.069560] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008 1219.071968] atai: SError: [ Commake 1

1219,074352] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED

1219.076716] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:40:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 4096 in

[1219.076716]

res 41/40:00:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>

[1219.081348] ata1.00: status: [ DRDY ERR] (1219.083638] ata1.00: error: [ UNC }

[1219.120304] I/O error, dev sda, sector 3692523528 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2 dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:

Loading files list file for package linux-hue-6.2-headers-6.2.0-33': cannot read /var/lib/dpkg/info/Linux-hue-6.

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2) saed@saad-notebook:"s
```

Even if I don't do anything after logging in, after a few minutes the following is printed onto the terminal

```
[ 646.240540] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8020 SErr 0x40000 action 0x6 frozen

[ 646.244406] ata1: SError: CommWake } 646.248330] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED

[ 646.252114] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:28:00:70:17/0a:00:dc:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 1310720 in
[ 646.252114] res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)

[ 646.259569] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

[ 646.263201] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED 
[ 646.266814] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:78:20:35:ec/00:00:aa:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 8192 out

[ 646.266814] res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)

[ 646.273834] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }

[ 646.718963] I/O error, dev sda, sector 3692523520 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 20 prio class 2
[ 649.535092] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20080 SErr 0x0 action 0x0

[ 649.538721] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008

[ 649.542257] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED

[ 649.545688] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:38:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 4096 in
[ 649.545688] res 41/40:00:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>

[ 649.552459] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 649.555843] ata1.00: error: { UNC }

[ 649.593183] I/O error, dev sda, sector 3692523528 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2

[ 652.341611] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x100900 SErr 0x40000 action 0x0

[ 652.344998] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008

[ 652.348268] atai: SError: { CommWake }

[ 652.351506] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 652.354661] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:40:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 4096 in

[ 652.354661] res 41/40:00:08:70:17/00:00:dc:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F> 
[ 652.360846] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR}
[ 652.363880] ata1.00: error: { UNC }

[ 652.401207] I/O error, dev sda, sector 3692523528 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
```

I also searched for `ata1: serror: commwake` from the errors above and applied the suggestion from [What do these ATA error messages mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060245/what-do-these-ata-error-messages-mean), which was to disable NCQ. But that changed nothing for me so I enabled it again just like the answer in that post suggested.

Please guide me how to troubleshoot this as I don't understand the errors I am getting.

Comment: I suggest you read your messages, eg. `I/O error, dev sda, sector 3692523528` which tells you a drive has failed. You remove that drive, replace it, and restore data from backups and the issue will be resolved. Do note even good components will fail in fed poor power; thus you can check the drive health (SMART), but you may also need to check RAM (ramtests), & of course power-supply; let alone motherboard (*for swollen caps*) etc. which can lead to hardware issues like your messages indicate.

Comment: @guiverc I am using an HP laptop. I also have windows 10 installed on the same drive therefore I am dual booting. When I check the drives that windows is using, it says they found no errors. Can it still be a bad drive? If I reinstall Ubuntu can that work?

Comment: The drive mentioned is SDA; windows will be installed to a different part of the drive such that *dual boot* will function, thus the errors maybe a sign of problems that will impact windows in days/weeks/months etc.. thus checking out the hardware is essential; as well as ensuring your windows backup (if on SDA; scsi/sata drive A) is complete & valid.