# Ext4-fs error, also file 'var/log/syslog'[7] write error, how to fix

Tags: filesystem

I love Linux Ubuntu but I am very ignorant to how it fails and about hardware. Could you please look at this jpeg and tell me how to proceed:

[image: My Issue]

Is it a hardware or a software problem. It's a Dell Latitude Laptop e7450. The problem started with Ubuntu 18.04, so I changed to 20.04 hoping it would go away, but it didn't. The problem would go away if I rebooted, but now it is more frequent. Once it starts, the computer is frozen and the icons on the side bar become gray squares

Comment: An OS upgrade cannot fix hardware problems; you have *logical* or *physical* issues on sda1, so explore your hardware first, before trying to resolve it via software changes.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   (you should be using *live* media & not your installed system until you've worked out your issue, be it drive problems PSU or other...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this drive failure or something else?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141862/is-this-drive-failure-or-something-else)

Comment: i'm able to boot from a flash drive. i did "sudo fsck /dev/sda1"  and it says its clean. Are there other simple tests that I can do to get a rough idea of the problem?

Comment: Checking drive health as provided in the first comment is where I'd start..   `fsck` only checks for logical errors in the file-system itself; not on the drive; where as SMART will look for drive/hardware issues as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: This are great pointers. I read them. I will try to install the smartmontools in the flash drive. Even though it's a Try Ubuntu 18.04 copy in the flash drive, it should be possible to install the smartmontools, right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to install smartmontools on the live disk.  Or you could get systemrescue disk which has it built into the live disk.

Comment: I was able to run the smart extended test and it passed. Now what? Sometimes the wifi internet connection keeps dropping like once a minute, even tough my tablet has no problem connecting. Other times, the internet connection seems steady for hours.