# Initframs issue during boot

Tags: boot

My wife's computer suddenly won't boot. It's running Ubuntu 22.04. It spits out the attached shown in pictures. I've tried googling, but I couldn't find anything. Her last 18 month's output from her cancer research is at risk, so she's stressed.

After running exit:

[image: during]

Comment: Ubuntu 22?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 22 Server install?  Your provided picture just shows drive IO errors which is a hardware issue; have you checked the health of the drive using SMART?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this drive failure or something else?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141862/is-this-drive-failure-or-something-else)

Comment: Also asked elsewhere, eg. https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/13s9hjx/initframs_issue/